# Process started via IIS can't connect to local database (.mdf file)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, mdf, .net-4.6

So I am running IIS to eventually do a `Process.Start(x)` to run an application that I included in the App_Data folder. 
The issue is that the Application needs to connect to a .mdf file that is included in the App_Data Folder as well.

When testing on IIS Express, the application runs fine and connects to the database. (Presumably because it opens the process and therefore the data connection as the Authenticated Windows User)

The issue is that IIS 7.5 seems to fail to connect to the database... I assume it is because it starts the application as application pool- which isn't going to be allowed in the .mdf file.

How do I go about fixing this issue?

I am aware of the alternative of using MSSQL Server- I am trying to keep the application self contained in the singular directory, so connecting that way isn't viable.

Comment: do you mean you want use mdf database without attaching sqlserver instance?

Comment: Essentially yes